# railsのurlをカスタマイズする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

具体的には

/posts/:id
↓
/p/:id

という感じにしたいのですが、現在はハードコーディングしちゃっています。
routesや`post_path(@post)`などで生成されるURLをカスタマイズするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

できるだけrailsのレールからはそれたくないのですが、今回は共有用のリンクとして短いものが好ましいのでよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

pathオプションをつけて、

```
resources :posts, :path => "p"
```

でいけるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

`resources :p, controller: :posts`

ではどうですか？